# Cypress Testing Async Await Functions with useContext and Next.js

Tags: async-await, next.js, cypress, settimeout, use-context

I am looking to ensure a notification appears within a `Cypress` integration test, with the correct message. I've created an `async await` function that has a `try/catch` block for the user to login, displaying different messages throughout their progress.

**Stages of notification** `status` **attribute:**

1. Before the `try/catch` block - `status` = "info"
2. At the end of `try` block - `status` = "success"
3. At the end of the `catch` block - `status` = "error"

**Example:**

```
  async function signIn(event) {
    notificationCtx.showNotification({
      message: "Logging in now",
      status: "info",
    });
    try {...
```

**Cypress Test:**

```
   it.only("case 'The InvalidParameterException shows a suitable  error'", () => {
      onFormLayoutsPage.testPlainTextInput("email", "team");
      onFormLayoutsPage.testPlainTextInput("password", "8s8d7fds!!");
      cy.get('[data-cy="login"]').click();
      cy.get('[data-cy="notification"]').should(
        "have.attr",
        "status",
        "error"
      );
    });
```

**Problem:**

The notification appears, but then disappears because of `setTimeout()`, before the `cy.get()` has a chance of seeing the component. The specific error is `Timed out retrying after 20000ms: Expected to find element: [data-cy="notification"], but never found it.`

**Component:**

```
<Snackbar open={true} onClose={notificationCtx.hideNotification}>
  <Alert
    data-cy="notification"
    onClose={notificationCtx.hideNotification}
    severity={status}
    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
  >
    {message}
  </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the `setTimeout()` using Cypress `cy.clock()` and `cy.tick()` commands.

```js
it("case 'The InvalidParameterException shows a suitable  error'", () => {

  cy.clock()                        // take control of when setTimeout() finishes

  onFormLayoutsPage.testPlainTextInput("email", "team");
  onFormLayoutsPage.testPlainTextInput("password", "8s8d7fds!!");
  cy.get('[data-cy="login"]').click();
  cy.get('[data-cy="notification"]').should("have.attr", "status", "error");

  cy.tick(3000)                     // allow time to pass & setTimeout to complete

  cy.get('[data-cy="notification"]').should('not.exist')
});
```